# Preview 15 of the Azure storage javascript library issue

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using the Azure storage javascript library for browsers. Some users have reported intermittent issues with IE, but it's been basically working. I am using it to upload local files to blobs.

I tried preview 15 and noticed there are no azure-storage.common files. The blob sample is failing with AzureStorage is undefined.

If I try to use the previously working code with the preview 14 common file, it fails with createBlobServiceWithSas is undefined.

Is there a trick to using preview 15 or should I wait for the next release?

Thanks for any information,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

There is a breaking change on preview 15 of the library:

> [[Breaking] Dropped `azure-storage.common.js`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/releases/tag/v0.2.8-preview.15).

So, you'll need to do the following changes with preview.15:

- Just only include `azure-storage.blob.js` in the HTML file for blob operation, and `azure-storage.common.js` is no longer needed.
- Using keyword `AzureStorage.Blob` instead of `AzureStorage` to access to Azure storage JavaScript APIs for blobs.

Comment: Please mark this answer as "correct" if it helped you :)